# What exactly the difference between register stack and memory stack? And what does the stack pointer store register stack address or memory stack add

Tags: c

What exactly is the difference between a register stack and a memory stack? And what does the stack pointer store?  Top of register stack address or memory stack address?  Does the computer have separate stack pointers to store the register stack address and the memory stack address or not?

I think the register stack is a collection of stack and memory; the stack is the memory allocated in RAM, and the computer has more than one stack pointer to store the register stack address and the memory stack address. I'm checking — am I wrong?

Comment: It seems like I got the answer in the very first response to [this query](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+exactly+the+difference+between+register+stack+and+memory+stack%3F)

Comment: None of these terms "register stack" or "memory stack" exist. There is only _the_ stack, one per process.

Comment: Asking about a "register stack" is as much a question about hardware architecture as it is about C.  Formally, the C language doesn't require a (memory) stack, though in practice, all implementations you're likely to come across (and that I've come across in 40-odd years of programming) have a stack.  The (memory) stack uses RAM (or level-N cache backed by RAM).  The stack pointer is a register that identifies a position in the memory stack.  Data is stored on the stack, including function parameters and return addresses.

Comment: I guess you should consult the definitions of those terms that were given you.  Neither one known to me as such.  There is *stack register*, however, which is a term for a CPU register used to track the hardware-managed stack.  And that hardware-managed stack lives in memory, so you could call it a "memory stack", though I'm unfamiliar with that usage.  On the other hand, the term *stack memory* is a fairly common description of some or all of the memory occupied by the hardware-managed stack.

Comment: @Lundin: Small correction: One per task. In a process with multiple threads, each thread requires a dedicated stack (iff the architecture is using stacks).

Comment: There might also be 2 stacks in parallel: one in tiny internal RAM, accessed via SP and which holds return addresses and registers pushed on interrupt etc. The other one in normal RAM, accessed via one of the GPRs, used for variables and parameters, etc. But that also doesn't fit to the suggested names

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a computer architecture question (as opposed to a data structures question.

The terms *memory stack* and *register stack* don't really exist. (Where "memory" and "register" are adjectives specifying a type of stack.)

You might be mixing up the order of the words. A *stack register* is definitely a thing in a CPU, and *stack memory* makes some sense:

Most CPU architectures have the equivalent of `push` and `pop` instructions which do two things at the same time:

- Write or read the value of a register to/from memory at the address specified by the current value of the *stack register*.
- Increment or decrement the stack register.

*Stack memory* -- or more commonly just "the stack" -- would be the area of memory set aside by the OS for the current thread's stack.

---

Other, less common, potentially related stacks:

Sometimes a *floating-point unit* (FPU) can have its own very small stack of floating point values. These are implemented in hardware registers (not memory), so you could call them a "register stack": https://stackoverflow.com/a/49848104/119527

Also, some less common CPU architectures provided a feature called [register windowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_window). This allowed for functions in a call stack to have their own (same-named) view of a subset of the available general-purpose registers. This acted kind of like a "register stack" as the window moved up/down with function calls/returns.

Comment: They are hardware architectures like SPARC and Itanium which do register stacking.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, I was just about to add a section on Sparc register windowing!

Answer (score -1):

These two term are different because In register stack organization the stack pointer point to stack which contains only data whereas memory stack organization the stack contain both instruction and data whereas in register.
In the former the number of register increases and in latter the register requirement is less.

They are similar in the context that both work on zero address instruction format. There coast is different the former is costlier whereas the latter is cheaper compared to former Speed of execution is same nearly in both the organization.

we can also say the former is subset of the latter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think I've seen "register stack" in some MCU datasheet (perhaps some AVR, can't remember), where it refers to the "collection of general purpose register".

In that case, the word *stack* is used with the meaning of "a bunch of", "the ensemble of" (registers). Sometimes I've found also "register file" with the same meaning, where the word *file* has nothing to do with the concept of files on a file system.

Instead, "stack register" means normally some specialized register that manages the (ram) stack; probably it points to the top (bottom) of the stack. The order of words is important!

For completeness, it is good to add that "stack memory" should refer to a region of memory used as a stack (last in, first out), while "memory stack" is strange but, willing to give it a meaning, could indicate some stack in (ram) memory opposed to some other stack not in (ram) memory. There are processors which have hardware (not in ram) stacks. In that case, "memory stack" could be used to precisely indicate some other stack (not the hardware one).